# read data from a list of strings

Tags: haskell

i have a data structure like this

```
data Something = Something Integer String String
```

and i want to convert

```
["Something", "3", "text", "42"]
```

to the data.

for now, i have

```
altRead :: Read a => [String] -> a
altRead = read . unwords . hack
    where 
        hack = map (\x -> if isNumber x then x else "\"" ++ x ++ "\"")
        isNumber = foldl (\b c -> isDigit c && b) True
```

but i forgot, that some numbers could be strings in the data structure. 
is there a simple solution for this or do i need to write a alternative read typeclass?

Comment: With the current list in your example there is no way around the `hack` function because not all the elements are readable.  Is there a reason why you're using a list instead of `"Something 3 \"text\" 42"`?

Comment: yes, i get this list from a parser, but the parser doesn't know the types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're writing a tiny parser atop some lexed tokens. You can't really implement a `Read` instance since `read :: Read a => String -> a` and you want to do `[String] -> a` for `a == Something`. You *can* take advantage of `Read` instances that already exist, though, to bootstrap parsing your `Integer`, for instance.

So let's try it. We'll parse a `Something` from the list of tokens.

```
import Safe -- gives us readMay :: Read a => String -> Maybe a

parseSomething :: [String] -> Maybe Something
parseSomething ("Something":strInt:stra:strb:_) = 
  do int <- readMay strInt
     return $ Something int stra strb
parseSomething _ = Nothing
```

We could do it a little more compactly using `Maybe` as an `Applicative`, too

```
import Control.Applicative

parseSomething :: [String] -> Maybe Something    
parseSomething ("Something":strInt:stra:strb:_) = 
  Something <$> readMay strInt <*> pure stra <*> pure strb
parseSomething _ = Nothing
```

Really, we should probably return any unconsumed tokens as well so we can continue parsing.

```
parseSomething :: [String] -> (Maybe Something, [String])
parseSomething ("Something":strInt:stra:strb:rest) = 
  (Something <$> readMay strInt <*> pure stra <*> pure strb, rest)
parseSomething rest = (Nothing, rest)
```

---

The reason I bring in all this structure to your parse is that this starts to head toward the space of parser combinators like `Parsec`. Whenever you've got a need for a complicated `Read` it begins to become useful to look at some of the really nice parsing libraries in Haskell.

Comment: +1 for pointing them in the direction they should go rather than the way they asked to go.

Comment: People need to solve jobs; sometimes a change of tooling is the way to go about it.

Answer (score 3):

With what you have, you don't really need to make it a typeclass. You can just do:

```
readSomething :: [String] -> Maybe Something
readSomething [_, n, s1, s2] = Just $ Something (read n) s1 s2
readSomething _              = Nothing
```

or, if you want to disambiguate on the first word:

```
data Something = Something Integer String String
               | SomethingToo String Integer

readSomething :: [String] -> Maybe Something
readSomething ["Something", n, s1, s2] = Just $ Something (read n) s1 s2
readSomething ["SomethingToo", s, n]   = Just $ SomethingToo s (read n)
readSomething _                        = Nothing
```

Comment: but i won't change the data structures, because i have a lot of big and different structures and it would be too much overhead.

Comment: Do you really need to add the `:: Integer` to `read n`?  The type checker should be able to figure it out.

Comment: Indeed, the type annotation is unnecessary.

Comment: You really shouldn't recommend `error` to indicate parse failure... it's like blowing up the city because a fire alarm went off. Catch failures in a `Maybe`/`Either` monad.

Comment: @tel: definitely agreed. Updated.

Comment: @user1188670: I don't understand. What would be too much overhead? If you used this code as the implementation of altRead, then you would get a working method, that doesn't make the error of your original code.

Answer (score 1):

In GHCI:

```
data Something = Something Integer String String deriving (Read, Show)

let somethingStrings = ["Something", "3", "text", "42"]

let escapeForSomething [a,b,c,d] = [a, b, "\""++c++"\"", "\""++d++"\""]

let something = read (unwords (escapeForSomething somethingStrings)) :: Something
```